# Confused about lower semicontinuous functions

Tags: optimization, continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, semicontinuous-functions

[image]

LSC is basically : For a function f to be lower semicontinuous at a means that if x is near a  then f(x) is greater than or equal to f(a), or at least nearly so.

But in the given graph, f is not LSC at x, as there exists points, call it s, where f(s) is less than f(x)

Comment: Unfortunately, your statement following “LSC is basically ...” is wrong.

Comment: I found the statement [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113049) and understood LSC based on that

Comment: Perhaps it depends on what “or at least nearly so” exactly means. – But think of $f(x) = -|x|$ which is continuous (and therefore lower semicontinuous) at $x=0$.

Comment: $f$ is LSC at $a$ if $\liminf_{x \to a} f(x) \ge f(a)$. That does *not* imply that $f(x) \ge f(a)$ near $a$.

Comment: Partially understood it. If possible, can you tell me how the given function in the image is lsc ?

Comment: What are the limits at the point in question?