# Definition of continuity in complete idempotent semirings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, continuity

Definition 11 taken from [Hardouin et al. 2018](http://dx.doi.org/10.1561/2600000013).

---

**Definition 11 (Continuity)**. A mapping $\Pi$ from a complete idempotent
semiring $D$ to a complete idempotent semiring $C$ is *lower semi-continuous*
(denoted l.s.c.) if for all finite or infinite sets $X \subseteq D$,

$$\Pi\left(\bigoplus_{x\in X} x\right) = \bigoplus_{x\in X} \Pi(x),$$

and it is *upper semi-continuous* (denoted u.s.c) if for all finite or infinite
sets $X \subseteq D$

$$\Pi\left(\bigwedge_{x\in X} x\right) = \bigwedge_{x\in X} \Pi(x).$$

It is *continuous* if it is both l.s.c. and u.s.c.

---

I struggle to understand how this relates to the [definition given in analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563713/different-definition-of-lower-semi-continuity) or [this definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182795/what-is-the-intuition-for-semi-continuous-functions) , we can take the $(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\oplus,\otimes)$ dioid for $C$ where $\otimes$ is addition and $\oplus$ is maximization. This definition doesn't need limits to exist, and doesn't define them either. I just don't get how it intuitively relates to this. I just don't see how this makes a function continuous over dioids.